# mvc3 controller not working - is path mapped wrong

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, maproute

Here is my code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Admin", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );  
        }
```

for first link it works well if i go to:
localhost/song
localhost/date
etc. it opens all links under home controller.

But for second maproute:
localhost/admin 
localhost/admin/index
- these link are not working? Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your default route must be last in the list, not first.

Second, You have two default routes.  There is no way for MVC to know which one to use, so it always chooses the first one that matches.  Instead, your Url for the admin one should be `"Admin/{action}/{id}"`